# check if value exist in array php

Tags: php, arrays

Have some problems with check if value exist in array. I have field in database where i save my data in `JSON` i do this in this way:

```
$this_will_be_saved = json_encode($array);
```

Now i need add some data to array but i need to check if array have that element already:

```
$this_will_be_saved = json_decode($this_will_be_saved, true);
```

Decoded array structure:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["rating"]=>
    int(9)
    ["userid"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["rating"]=>
    int(9)
    ["userid"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["rating"]=>
    int(9)
    ["userid"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["rating"]=>
    int(1)
    ["userid"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [4]=>
  array(2) {
    ["rating"]=>
    int(7)
    ["userid"]=>
    int(1)
  }
}
```

I try check if new added value exist in array but array_search not working :/

```
$key = array_search($userid, array_column($this_will_be_saved, 'userid'));
if ( $key ) {
    // found
} else {
    // not found
}
```

It always not founding anything :/ even if i user id already exist...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`array_search()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) returns the first corresponding key, if it finds the value in the array.

The first key of your array is `0` that is the same as `false` (returned by `array_search()` when it cannot find the value in the array) when evaluated in boolean context.
An [`if`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php) expression is such a context (`if ($key)` in your code).

Accordingly, if `$userid` is `1`, `array_search()` returns `0` and the `if` statement correctly takes the `else` branch.

Use [`in_array()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) to check if a value exists in an array:

```
$found = in_array($userid, array_column($this_will_be_saved, 'userid'));
if ($found) {
    // found
} else {
    // not found
}
```